# Filling a dataframe from a dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following dataframe as an example.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=["green","yellow","red","pink"], columns=["bear","dog","cat"], dtype=None, copy=False)
```

[image]

I have the following dictionary with keys and values that are the same or related to the index and columns od my dataframe.

```
d = {"green":["bear","dog"], "yellow":["bear"], "red":["bear"]}
```

I would like to fill my dataframe according with the keys and values that are presented and if the key is not present I want to fill with empty.

Desired output

[image]

I only can think about making lists and looping for. Is there an easy way to implement this? or functions that can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use loopd by dictionary and set `True` values, then replace all missing rows by by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `Empty` and last replace missing values by `fillna`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        df_test.loc[k, x] = 'Yes'

df_test = df_test.mask(df_test.isnull().all(axis=1), 'Empty').fillna('No')
print (df_test)
         bear    dog    cat
green     Yes    Yes     No
yellow    Yes     No     No
red       Yes     No     No
pink    Empty  Empty  Empty
```

Comment: it will also fill the ones that are not a dictionary key with No instead of Empty

Comment: @may - solution was modify, please check it.

Comment: Thank you! I think now works! I will accept it soon :)

Comment: sorry, does not work for the empty cases for the ones that are in the pink index

Comment: @may - Do you think empty list in dicts? Or `NaN`s values ?

Comment: I redid the dictionary when pink is not a key so everything should be filled with empty

Comment: For me it working nice, there is no last pink row. Problem is with real data? Or also with sample?

Comment: it was with my sample in the example. The condition is that the index such as pink is not a key and it should be filled as empty

Comment: @may - I understand now, solution is changed.

Comment: only yours work! Sorry, this is the best answer for my question :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a largely vectorised solution via [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.reindex`:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

res = pd.get_dummies(df.reindex(df_test.index), prefix='', prefix_sep='')\
        .reindex(columns=df_test.columns)\
        .fillna(0).applymap({0: 'No', 1: 'Yes'}.get)\
        .reindex(index=np.hstack((df_test.index, df.index.difference(df_test.index))))\
        .fillna('Empty')

print(res)

         bear    dog    cat
green     Yes    Yes     No
yellow    Yes     No     No
red       Yes     No     No
pink    Empty  Empty  Empty
```

Comment: Same problem. Pink is not in the dictionary  and it disappears with this solution

Comment: @may, No, I didn't make up my result.. `pink` does appear as a final row. Hence the `index=np.hstack((df_test.index, df.index.difference(df_test.index)))` part.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by doing:

```
# You can use elements that are not in the original dataframe
# and the row will be filled with empty

index_list = ["green", "yellow", "red", "pink", "purple"]

replace_dict = {True: 'Yes', False: 'No', np.nan:'Empty'}

df_test.loc[list(d.keys())].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.index.isin(d[x.name]),
        index=x.index), axis=1).reindex(index_list).replace(replace_dict) 

         bear    dog    cat
green     Yes    Yes     No
yellow    Yes     No     No
red       Yes     No     No
pink    Empty  Empty  Empty
purple  Empty  Empty  Empty
```

**Explanation**

You can accomplish what you want by checking whether the columns of the dataframe are present in the corresponding field of the dict:

```
df_test.loc[list(d.keys())].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.index.isin(d[x.name]),
    index=x.index), axis=1)

        bear    dog    cat
green   True   True  False
yellow  True  False  False
red     True  False  False
```

And then reindex according to the keys of the dict to fill find missing colors and fill them with empty:

```
index_list = ["green","yellow","red","pink", "purple"]

df_test.loc[list(d.keys())].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.index.isin(d[x.name]),
       index=x.index), axis=1).reindex(index_list)

        bear    dog    cat
green   True   True  False
yellow  True  False  False
red     True  False  False
pink     NaN    NaN    NaN
purple   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Then, if you want to change the values you can replace them by using a dictionary like this:

```
replace_dict = {True: 'Yes', False: 'No', np.nan:'Empty'}

df_test.loc[list(d.keys())].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.index.isin(d[x.name]),
        index=x.index), axis=1).reindex(index_list).replace(replace_dict) 

         bear    dog    cat
green     Yes    Yes     No
yellow    Yes     No     No
red       Yes     No     No
pink    Empty  Empty  Empty
purple  Empty  Empty  Empty
```

Comment: @may - So it working for you with `index=["green","yellow","red","pink"]` ?

Comment: Yes, it does! Just put the list in `reindex`. If not present, it'll be filled with `Empty`. Added an example.