# How to make dictionary values same across all keys?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping a website for apartment sales market analysis. I have 100+ dictionary keys (price, location, URL, zip code, number of floors, etc.). For this, I am using `Selenium` to retrieve values for those parameters and appending the values to the dictionary.

However, I encounter issues where some ads don't have these attributes. This causes the dictionary values to not have the same length and become misaligned when converting them into a `Data frame`.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Empty dictionary
all_data = {'URL': []}

# Counter variable
counter = 1

# url_list is the list of URLS where all data comes from.

# Open from old to new ads. 
reversed_url_list = url_list[::-1]
for url_in_list in reversed_url_list:

    # Initalizing the driver for Chrome browser 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    # Maximizing windows
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Open the website
    driver.get(url_in_list)
    sleep(3)

    # Get all HTML source from web page
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

    # Find all inactive ads by class tag
    inactive_listing = soup.find(class_="listing-inactive")

    # If ads are inacrive, then continue
    if inactive_listing:
        print(f'Skipping {url_in_list} due to inactivity.')
        continue
    else:
        # Else find all elements with class name 'info-table row'
        try:
            # For each row in 'info table'
            for row in soup.find_all('div', class_='info-table__row'): 

                # Find the title of this row and save as a key
                key_element = row.find('dt', class_='info-table__title') 
                # Find the corresponding value for this key and save it as a value
                value_element = row.find('dd', class_='info-table__value') 
                key = key_element.get_text(strip=True)
                value = value_element.get_text(strip=True)
                # If key is found in dictionary, the append value
                if key in all_data:
                    all_data[key].append(value)
                # Else create a dictionay key and append a value
                else:
                    all_data[key] = [value]
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        
    all_data['URL'].append(url_in_list)
    driver.quit()
    print(f'{str(counter)} data has been scrapped. {str(len(url_list) - counter)} remaining.')
    counter +=1
```

Using this approach, let's say if an ad doesn't have  `No of floors`, then so this value won't be appended in the dictionary but the rest of values are. In the next iteration, if this value found, it will be appended in wrong position. This causes an issue when converting the `dict` to `DataFrame` because number of values won't be the same size and wrong values appended to wrong place.

Therefore, I would like to add `None` instead if any of dictionary key not found in the loop for each ads.

Comment: How does a typical dict looks like? Are there mandatory fields? Please share.

Comment: Hi @balderman, 

All dictionary keys are mandatory. But not all keys are found in typical website. So In that case I need to add/append  ```None``` as a value to dictionary

Comment: And do you "know" those fields? I mean that you are expecting to get  well known keys in the dict?

Comment: If these fields are not known beforehand, you could maybe create an empty dataframe with dimensions of `all_data` and then fill it in (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834173/filling-a-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-keys-and-values)) with the values of `all_data`. With `fillna()` you can replace `NaN` with `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care you are overwriting values of your `dict` because keys have to be unique - a unique key could be the url:

```
all_data = {}
...
for url_in_list in reversed_url_list:
    ...
    all_data[url_in_list] = {}
    ...
    for row in soup.find_all('div', class_='info-table__row'):
       ...
       all_data[url_in_list].update({key:value})
```

---

However you could also work with a `list` of `dicts` - Creating a `DataFrame` from this will create all columns also from missing keys and set them to `NaN`:

```
all_data = []
...
for url_in_list in reversed_url_list:
    ...
    d = {'url':url_in_list}
    ...
    for row in soup.find_all('div', class_='info-table__row'):
       ...
       d.update({key:value})
    all_data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(all_data)
```

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'url':'some_url','f1':'v1','f2':'v2'},
        {'url':'some_other_url','f2':'v2','f3':'v3'},
        {'url':'some_other_url','f5':'v5'}
    ]
)
```

Results in:

|  | url | f1 | f2 | f3 | f5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | some_url | v1 | v2 | nan | nan |
| 1 | some_other_url | nan | v2 | v3 | nan |
| 2 | some_other_url | nan | nan | nan | v5 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you "know" the fields you need, the code below will work for you and padd the dict with `None`

```
import copy

# Assuming you are expecting to get 5 well know fields [f1...f5]
scraping_data = {'f1': 'f1_value', 'f3': 'f3_value'}
dict_template = {'f1': None, 'f2': None, 'f3': None, 'f4': None, 'f5': None}
data = copy.deepcopy(dict_template)
for k, v in scraping_data.items():
    data[k] = v
print(data)
```

output

```
{'f1': 'f1_value', 'f2': None, 'f3': 'f3_value', 'f4': None, 'f5': None}
```